# Wrong text indention for self numbered list when next to floating element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, counter, indentation

Somehow I could not find a solution for my self-styled list numbers. If they are next to a floating element the list numbers get pulled into the image's margin.

The list numbers should be inline with the text blocks surrounding the list. Maybe i missed something simple.

HTML:

```
<article class="teaser">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Number One</li>
        <li>Number Two</li>
        <li>Number Three</li>
        <li>Number Four</li>
        <li>Number Five<br/>has line-break</li>
        <li>Number Six</li>
        <li>Number Seven</li>
        <li>Number Eight</li>
        <li>Number Nine</li>
        <li>Number Hundred</li>
    </ol>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Number One</li>
        <li>Number Two</li>
        <li>Number Three</li>
        <li>Number Four</li>
        <li>Number Five<br/>has line-break</li>
        <li>Number Six</li>
        <li>Number Seven</li>
        <li>Number Eight</li>
        <li>Number Nine</li>
        <li>Number Hundred</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 280px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 25px;
    counter-reset: lis;
}
li {
    counter-increment: lis;
}
li:nth-child(n+10) {
    counter-increment: lis +91;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(lis)".\00a0";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -25px;
    color: red;
    min-width: 25px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGpmd/2/)

P.S. The list numbers must have a minimum width for 1-99 but must grow dynamically from 100-∞ like it is now.

Comment: if you think about text-indent, it will break the list if there is no floating element next to it

Comment: no margin-right: 20px;

Comment: or list-style-position: inside;

Comment: Can you be more precise where to add these 20px?
Btw I am sure, if list-style is none, list-style-position will not affect anything.

Comment: .image {
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 280px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

Comment: That will push also the paragraphs and other things...

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `ol` CSS definition.

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 25px;
    counter-reset: lis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That way it's left padding won't merge into the floating image.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/eGpmd/5/

Comment: ok, now the list cannot flow around the image if longer, but it seems to be the best solution atm.

Comment: So you mean that you "accept this as the best answer"? ;)